# DataTable paging by tbody instead of tr elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, web, datatables

I have problem with slow loading of page with table of many rows. So I decided to make a pagination and that way make it a little bit faster. But, my rows are created from tbody elements where each tbody element includes 2 tr elems.

Here is example:

```
<table id="mydatatable" class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>
            <div>BIG CONTENT</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>
            <div>BIG CONTENT</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

On the mydatable ID I'm calling .DataTable() function to make a sorting of rows and pagination. Sorting is fully working but there is problem with pagination, which is absolutely not working :D

Can someone help me solve this problem somehow?

Thank you.

F.

Comment: DataTables only support one `<tbody>` at a time.  It does not support `colspan`'s either.

Comment: Thanks, I know that.. but the problem is not to paginate by <tr> tags but by <tbody> tags anyhow.. It doesn't have to use DataTables

Comment: You can place a whole <table> inside a <tr> and set pagLength to show one row at a time. Cannot see the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that structure solved my problem.